# Raspberry (C#) connects to MySQL when using IP but fails when using server name

Tags: c#, mysql, raspberry-pi3

My setup is a Raspberry Pi3 with WPF-app that connects to a MySQL DB on a mini computer via wireless router. After minor changes in the app the Raspberry would not connect anymore. When using the IP-address of the mini computer it connects every time, switching back to server name it fails (“cannot connect to any of the specified hosts…”). The same app on the developing computer however connects using the server name.

That tells me the Raspberry is the problem. I set up a brand-new Raspberry with a brand-new SD-Card, but still the same. 
On the developing side I updated VS Studio and set the min. target version to the newest (17134). But nothing helped. I tried debug, release and a package, all the same.

This setup started and worked reliably more than 100 times, and there is the same setup out for field testing, starting every day in the last 3 months, running 14 hours and never failed.

I searched 34 google pages of stackoverflow-questions related to MySQL connection but found nothing similar. I should have little hope therefore that someone has a clue…

Comment: That means there's a DNS problem. Perhaps you are using the wrong name. Can you *ping* the server's name? What does `ping -a` produce when you use it with the IP ? Perhaps the real DNS name isn't what you think

Comment: It was connectiing from the developer computer using the name though, but it did not today. I deactivated the firewall and it connects  . Don't know why, thought the port 3306 would pin-hole the firewall, and obviously it did until recently. Your feedback helped me to look into something else than the Raspberry. Thank you, Panagiotis!